# How/why does this generating function approach work?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, combinations, generating-functions

Suppose I wanted to find the number of solutions of $$e_1 + e_2 + e_3 = 17$$ where $e_1, e_2,$ and $e_3$ are nonnegative integers with $2 \leq e_1 \leq 5, 3 \leq e_2 \leq 6, 4 \leq e_3 \leq 7$.

The solution [apparently] lies in the fact that the number of solutions with the indicated constraints is the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\sum_{k=2}^5 x^k \bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=3}^6 x^k \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{k=4}^7 x^k\bigg) $$Why is this the case? Why, on a fundamental level, do elementary generating function-based counting methods (such as this one) work?

Comment: Try and work through an example by hand, the arithmetic you do should help to show what is going on behind the scenes. I would work with a much smaller example though.

Comment: In how many ways can you get a monomial of the $x^{17}$ form from the product $$(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7) $$ ? Isn't it exactly what you want to count?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Correct; in fact, that was the original form of the statement as it appeared in the textbook (I used summation notation for brevity). I don't understand why what we're trying to count corresponds to the coefficient of $x^{17}$, however.

Comment: I remeber that exactly the same exercise was posted here some days ago, so you should try to find it.

Comment: @TiwaAina: we get a monomial of the $x^{17}$ form by multiplying $x^5,x^6,x^6$, or by multiplying $x^5,x^5,x^7$, or by multiplying $x^4,x^6,x^7$. Three ways, associated to the representations $5+6+6, 5+5+7, 4+6+7$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That made it clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments a $x^{17}$ monom iff you multiply $x^l$,$x^m$,$x^n$ from the first, second, third sum (i.e. $2\leq l\leq 5, 3\leq m\leq 6, 4\leq n \leq 7$) with $l+n+m=17$. So the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the product is exactly given by the number of possibilities for $l+m+n=17$.